# How do I detect a null reference in C#?

Tags: c#

How do I determine if an object reference is null in C# w/o throwing an exception if it is null?

i.e. If I have a class reference being passed in and I don't know if it is null or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What Robert said, but for that particular case I like to express it with a guard clause like this, rather than nest the whole method body in an if block:

```
void DoSomething( MyClass value )
{
    if ( value == null ) return;
    // I might throw an ArgumentNullException here, instead

    value.Method();
}
```

Comment: I think you mean 'value == null'. Calling value.Method() on a null object would be bad.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I get for copy/pasting.  Fixed now.

Comment: > I might throw an exception here, too: if so, probably throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

Comment: What I was wanting was a way to put a default value or behavior in if the class was null.  I wanted to avoid an exception since I knew exactly what I wanted to do.  Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 15):

testing against null will never* throw an exception

```
void DoSomething( MyClass value )
{
    if( value != null )
    {
        value.Method();
    }
}
```

---

* never as in *should never*. As @Ilya Ryzhenkov points out, an *incorrect* implementation of the != operator for MyClass could throw an exception. Fortunately Greg Beech has a good blog post on [implementing object equality in .NET](http://gregbee.ch/blog/implementing-object-equality-in-dotnet).

Comment: There's at least one way it'll throw:  `theObj.Equals( null)`

Comment: or if ( value == null)
  Thanks!

Comment: @Mike B. Technically that's not testing against null, but invoking the method Equals() on theObj, which, as you say, will throw an exception if theObj reference is null.

Answer (score 5):

Note, that having operator != defined on MyClass would probably lead do different result of a check and NullReferenceException later on. To be absolutely sure, use object.ReferenceEquals(value, null)

Answer (score 4):

```
if(p != null)
{
   DoWork(p);
}
```

Also, the 'as' keyword is helpful if you want to detect if a class is of the right type and use it all at once.

```
IExample e = p as IExample;
if(e != null)
    DoWork(e);
```

In the above example if you were to cast e like (IExample)e it will throw an exception if e does not implement IExapmle. If you use 'as' and e doesn't implement IExample e will simply be null.

Comment: If you are using the "as" keyword, might as well throw in the "is" as well:

if(p is IExample) { DoWork(p as IExample) }

as "is" will eval to false if p is null.

Comment: If you do `is` then you should just do a direct cast following that instead of as, since as will add an extra, unnecessary null check.

Answer (score 4):

If you look in the majority of the .NET framework source code you will see they put checks like this at the top of their functions.

```
public void DoSomething(Object myParam)
{
  if (myParam == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("myParam");

  // Carry on
}
```

Comment: Good advice for a public interface where a null reference is invalid in the context of the called method.

Answer (score 3):

With C# 6.0 this is much more elegant; you can do it in one line :-)

```
value?.Method();
```

If "value" is null, nothing will happen - and no exception.

Answer (score 1):

It's nit picky, but I always code these like ...

```
if (null == obj) {
   obj = new Obj();
}
```

instead of

```
if (obj == null) {
   obj = new Obj();
}
```

to avoid accidently writing

```
if (obj = null) {
   obj = new Obj();
}
```

because

```
if (null = obj) {
   obj = new Obj();
}
```

will give you a compiler error

Comment: if (obj = null) gives you the "possible misuse of =" compiler warning

Comment: In C# your condition expression must be a boolean, which obj = null never will be (obj = true, on the other hand is). Yoda code is not recommended in C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
(YourObject != Null)
```

you can compare to null?

If it's null instead of throwing an exception you can initialize your object. You can use the Null Pattern.

Comment: fyi - YouTube video of a code example for the Null Pattern http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hp1Y9bhail8

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are using value types you can read about nullable types: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mosessaur/nullabletypes08222006164135PM/nullabletypes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have in the application's xaml.cs application derivative definition:

```
private SortedList myList;
```

And I want to be able to re-use my constructors.  So I needed:

```
if ( myList == null)
   myList = new SortedList();
```

Thanks Robert!